# Google Analytics API error "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together."

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have to retrieve as many different metrics from my GA ecommerce as I can all at once. I'm using google api ruby client for that. And keep getting an error:

```
"message"=>"Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together."
```

for example, for this request:

```
result = client.execute(api_method: api_method.data.ga.get, parameters: {
    'ids'        => 'ga:95561781',
    'start-date' => Date.new(2006,1,1).to_s,
    'end-date'   => Date.today.to_s,
    'dimensions' => 'ga:source,ga:medium,ga:country,ga:transactionId,ga:affiliation,ga:productSku,ga:productName',
    'metrics'    => 'ga:sessions,ga:transactionRevenue,ga:transactions,ga:uniquePurchases,ga:totalValue,ga:transactionTax'
})
```

How do I know what request metrics and dimensions I can combine and what not? And how can I retrieve as many data as I can?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not all dimensions and metrics can be queried together.

> Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together

Means that your request contains dimensions or metrics that can not be mixed.

You may use the [Dimensions and Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) developer reference to see which metrics and dimensions can be used together in your query

Comment: I think I used it already. How do I know which can be used together?

Comment: roll over each name and select its checkbox to see all the other values that can be combined in the same query