# Error 400 "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together."

Tags: google-analytics

I tried to get the following query results but got error 400 "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together."  I checked the dimensions and metrics reference guide but cannot find any clue.  Please advise.

**metrics:** ga:hits 
**dimensions:** ga:dateHour,ga:minute,ga:eventAction,ga:sourceMedium,ga:eventCategory,ga:previousPagePath,ga:pagePath 
**filters:** ga:eventCategory=~^test

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has different scopes for dimensions and metrics: Hits  and Sessions.

When calling hits (or 'hit-level metrics'), you must call dimensions only within that scope.

Here is a great post by Avinash Kaushik that explains this well: http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/hits-sessions-metrics-dimensions-web-analytics/.

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29155189/39396), if you go to Google Analytics [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets), you can select the checkbox next to metrics and dimensions.  The page will gray out those other metrics or dimensions which are incompatible with your selection(s).