# com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have getting an error like

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
>   {
>     "code" : 400,
>     "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "message" : "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together.",
>       "reason" : "badRequest"
>     } ],
>     "message" : "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together."
>
> Metrics are below:
>   "ga:uniquePurchases,ga:itemRevenue,ga:transactionTax,ga:transactionShipping
>
> Dimensions below: "ga:productName";

```
 if (accessToken != null && refreshToken != null) {
            JacksonFactory jacksonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

             GoogleCredential credential =new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(netHttpTransport)
                                                   .setJsonFactory(jacksonFactory).setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).build();
                               credential.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                               credential.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
                               analytics=new Analytics.Builder(netHttpTransport, jacksonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
            try {
                //AT a time we can get only 7 dimensions and 10 metrics
                apiQuery = analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + gleTokenInf.getProfileId(), TimeStamp1, TimeStamp2,getMetrics());
                apiQuery.setDimensions(getDimensions());
                gaData = apiQuery.execute();
                log.info("Succesfully got the data for GA MOM Report from Analytics Interface ");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Analytics API error "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152101/google-analytics-api-error-selected-dimensions-and-metrics-cannot-be-queried-to)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query all combinations of dimensions and metrics in GA API. Your query will work if  ga:productName is replaced with ga:transactionId.

Test API queries here here - https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: Thank you Alen.I got it now.